# Why does "/dev/stdin" not exist when here-doc is used?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I am using `git-bash`:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

---

I declared the following simple function:

```
f() { local f=${1:-/dev/stdin}; sed 's/a/b/g' "$f"; }
```

When I use a pipe or a file to feed input to the function, everything works fine:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
$ f file
b
b
c
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | f
b
b
```

But when I use a here-doc or a here-string, `/dev/stdin` seems not to exist:

```
$ f << eof
> a
> b
> eof
sed: can't read /dev/stdin: No such file or directory
```

Although, using `cat` with here-doc seems to work just fine:

```
$ cat << eof
> a
> b
> eof
a
b
```

---

**This code works fine in my Linux distro.** How could I change it so that it works with `stdin` or a file even in `git-bash`?

Comment: works for me. I'm using bash-4.3.48(1)